# I'm having issues updating my unity version from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: unity, updates

I just installed ubuntu on my chromebook and have the 16.04 version, i wanted to get the 18.04 version but i couldn't update it beacuse i got an error saying "You are not allowed to perform this action" with the following "You don't have the required privileges to perform this action".

After i click on settings it opens up the Software and updates tab and when i press close i get another error something about

org.debian.apt.update-cache

I also cant install any apps from the USC

Any solutions?

Comment: You haven't provide details as to what commands you used to attempt *release-upgrade*.  That message could be because you didn't elevate privileges, but without specific details as to your command it could be something else. Also was your 16.04 system fully-upgraded (ie. upgraded to 16.04.6) which should be done first...

Comment: Well i havent used any commands, meaby i havent fully-upgraded beacuse i domt know how to.

Comment: org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.86'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache

Comment: Thats the error i get

Comment: Also found that the network tab on settings says "The system network services are not compatible with this version"